# How To sort an array of nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, nested

I have an array like this

```
var array = [{
    order: 3,
    sub - array: [{
        order: 2
    },{
        order: 1
    }]
},{
    order: 2,
    sub - array: [{
        order: 2
    },{
        order: 1
    }]
}];​
```

Now I want to sort the the complete collection on the attribute `order`, so both the outer
as well as inner arrays should get sorted based on the attribute order.

The final output should look like this.

```
var array = [{
    order: 2,
    sub - array: [{
        order: 1
    },{
        order: 2
    }]
},{
    order: 3,
    sub - array: [{
        order: 1
    },{
        order: 2
    }]
}];​
```

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: @jbabey structure can be any number of levels deep, sorry didn't get the accept answers part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var propertySort = function(a, b){
    return a.order > b.order ? 1 : (a.order < b.order ? -1 : 0);
    }

var reorder = function(arr){
    var l = arr.length;
    while (l--){
        if (arr[l]['sub-array']){
            reorder(arr[l]['sub-array']);
        }
    }
arr.sort(propertySort);
};

reorder(arr);

console.log(arr);
```

This should re-order the array for any number of nested levels.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.sort` and call it on `array` and subsequently on each element of `array` with an appropriate compare function. 
Something like this should work:

```
array.sort(function (e1, e2) {
  return (e1.order - e2.order);
});

array.forEach(function(e) {
  e["sub-array"].sort(function (e1, e2) {
    return (e1.order - e2.order);
  });
});
```